# Ubuntu first time user -desktop or server?

Tags: 12.04

Looking to delve into Linux so I choose Ubuntu. Not quite sure where to go as regard to desktop or server installations. Can I install desktop then server on top/next to it or would that need a multiboot disk with both on two partitions?
I have a clean laptop to work (no M$) with but im not sure where as yet what direction I want to go in with Linux. Im looking to study the linux foundation sys admin and go from there.
Im not sure that this would lead to a career just one qualification but you have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop and server tasks are the same OS, the choice is just about what optional software you'd like the installer to start you off with.  It is a choice of whether you want to install software suitable for desktop, such as a desktop environment (like Windows), or software suitable for a server, which will have no desktop environment and use a prompt (like DOS).

If you choose one it is still possible to alter it later.  And it is possible to have a desktop environment installed but then also install server software (like web servers, etc).

Comment: That`s the answer I was looking for. I want to use it as an alternative computer for one, so a desktop would be ideal with all the uses that can have. Then possibly add server software to delve into that further because I do a bit of web design but use hosted shared server which was ideal because I didnt have the experience to take on board my own hosting capabilities at first. Obviously gaining experience in the design and coding, I learnt more regarding the integration into the server side of things. I have dabbled with WAMP on the pc so time to move into Linux itself.

Comment: For what it's worth I now have cheap VPS accounts which I do development work on and run server software (eg nginx/mysql/php) on them, rather than running a web server on my local machine.  And I run Ubuntu or Debian on those VPSes.  Running web server on local machine makes it a hassle to do any development on that server when you're away from your desk - you'd have to leave it running and ensure it's accessible from the outside world.  You can get a VPS that is suitable enough for dev work for like $3 a month, which is not much.